# Como Verificar a existência de uma Id em um documento via JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, id

Estou programando o sistema do meu TCC e nele estou criando um site que contem dois tipos de ID na Div container de cada pagina: `fundo_index` no Index e `fundo_base` nas demais paginas.

Eu preciso fazer uma verificação para saber qual destas IDs existe para assim disparar uma função especifica somente para o Index, como estou usando JQuery, eu pesquisei e encontrei o metodo`.hasClass();` que faz essa verificação nas classes de um elemento, porem não consegui encontrar o equivalente dele para IDs.

Eu gostaria de perguntar a vocês qual é esse equivalente deste método para IDs e se não existir, qual é a maneira de fazer esta verificação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var existeFundoIndex = document.getElementById('fundo_index');
```

Essa é a maneira de saber se existe um elemento na página com a ID `fundo_index`. É JavaScript puro, nativo. Para coisas simples como esta não é preciso jQuery.

Se existir o elemento então a variável terá um ponteiro para esse elemento, ou seja terá valor boleano `true`, se não existir terá o valor `null`.

Podes fazer lógica à volta disso, ou testar outros elementos. Por exemplo:

```
var existeFundoIndex = document.getElementById('fundo_index');
if (existeFundoIndex){
   // fazer algo
} else {
   // fazer outra coisa
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
var existeFundoIndex = document.getElementById('fundo_index');
var existeFundoBase = document.getElementById('fundo_base');
if (existeFundoIndex){
   // fazer algo
} else if (existeFundoBase) {
   // fazer outra coisa
} else {
  alert('Não há nenhum!...);
}
```

Ou outra variante que precises...

#### Mais info:

- [`document.getElementById()` na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) <sup>Em Inglês</sup>

Comment: funcionou aqui, vlw ae, não achava que seria tão facil assim

Answer (score 4):

Use [`$(seletor).length`](https://api.jquery.com/length/) para verificar a quantidade de elementos que dão *match* de acordo com o seletor. Um `id` é único por documento, logo o valor obtido ao chamar `length` poderá ser somente: `1` no caso o elemento estar presente no html ou `0` se não existir.

```js
$(function(){
  if($('#fundo_index').length)
    console.log('tem #fundo_index');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='fundo_index'>
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa necessariamente usar jQuery pra isso

```
if(document.getElementById('fundo_index'))
    //elemento com id "fundo_index" existe
else
    //elemento com id "fundo_index" não existe
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `has-attribute`. Afinal, o ID é um atributo de qualquer forma.

Neste link tem o exemplo: [Has Attribute](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

Comment: sim, mas como fazer isto em todos os elementos da página para verificar se um deles possui o atributo `id`?